# JPA doesn't read my updation in columns in my entity class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have a entity

```
@Entity
public class A{
    @Column(name = "a")
    private column a;

    @Column(name = "b")
    private column b;
}
```

Table is created in database with name A.

Now I want to update columns in my entity

```
@Entity
public class A{
    @Column(name = "a", length = 1000)
    private column a;

    @Column(name = "b")
    private column b;
}
```

JPA doesn't read length=1000 in my column a

Any answer would be appreciable

Edit:
My config

```
  jpa:
generate-ddl: true
properties:
  hibernate:
    order_inserts: true
    generate_statistics: false
    jdbc:
      batch_size: 1000
hibernate:
  naming:
    physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
  ddl-auto: update
show-sql: true
```

Comment: How does your configuration looks like?

Comment: shared the config please check @Jens

Comment: "JPA doesn't read length=1000 in my column a" what do yo mean by that? What do you expect to happen and what does really happen?

Comment: What is the type of your columns?

Comment: @JensSchauder I want my column to have length=1000 after i add this in my entity, but what happens is that it remains same like before

Comment: @Jens String and integer (data types of columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!!Answering my own question!!

My configuration :

```
hibernate.ddl-auto : update
```

this does not modify the columns and neither delete them from table even after updating the entity.

The correct solution is to do this through migration using flyway

Documentation : https://flywaydb.org/documentation/

We can write native sql queries in the project only and update the length for the column